# How to check if installed Trusted CAs are not dangerous?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

I've checked my Windows 7 installed Trusted Certificate Authorities using MMC tool as below:

[image]

Questions are:

1. How can I be sure that they are genuine and are installed by Microsoft and not by a third-party software which I have installed on my Windows?
2. What certificates I should check? Is that enough to check Trusted Root Certificate Authorities only or I need to check other directories in above picture too?
3. Does Google Chrome and Firefox use these Certificates to verify website's certificates or they have their own CA certificates?

Comment: And as for question #3: Chrome uses the systems CA store and Firefox comes with its own.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I searched almost all the above certificate's Thumbprints in www.crt.sh, but nothing found. Why?

Comment: This is a different question than your original one and should thus be asked as a new question and not a comment. In this question you should also provide more details, i.e. not "almost all" but the specific certificates you expected to be available there and why.